# Perl while loops and reading lines

Tags: perl, diff

Each record has 4 lines:

Like the following:

```
@NCYC361­11a03.q1k bases 1 to 1576
GCGTGCCCGAAAAAATGCTTTTGGAGCCGCGCGTGAAAT
+
!)))))****(((***%%((((*(((+,**(((+**+,­
```

There are two files in which 1 file corresponded to the other

there are an array of seqeunces A1 
So read 1 record at a time from file 1. read record from file 2. if the sequence in record  1 file 1 (line 2) matches the seuqnece in the array A1, i print the record from file 2 to an output file so on...but the point is i need to read a record at a time.... how would i break out of the inner loop so that i can read the next record from the file 1 and then compare it to the next record in file 2

Comment: Do I understand correctly that only lines with same number can ever match across the files?

Comment: What inner loop? There is no inner loop here afaics.

Comment: Could you explain what your goal is ... do you want to compare the files?

Comment: Well since I am essentially doing this with each record that has 4 lines. So I read a record from file 1 extract it get the sequence. then read the 1st record from file 2 and do the appropriate stuff as needed. However im stuck on how to get out the inner loop read the next record from file 1 again...

Answer (score 1):

If you ask about controlling nested loops you can do that with labels.

Example:

```
OUTER:
while(<>){
    for(@something){
        last OUTER;
    }
}
```

See [`last`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/last.html) for example.

Answer (score 1):

In case only lines with same number could ever match, you don't really need more than one loop. You can call reading operation (`<>`, `read`, `sysread`) wherever you want. It only usually placed directly in loop because it conveniently returns undef and breaks it when work is done.

```
while(defined(my $first_line = <FIRST>)){
   my $second_line = <SECOND>;
   if($first_line eq $second_line){
      print "match\n";
   } else {
      print "no match\n";
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From your sentence *I need to check if the sequence matches any with the sequence from the second* I gather that you want to check whether *any* lines in the two files match?

If you need to read a file several times then you can use `seek` to rewind to the start of it without reopening it.

This program shows the idea.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh1, '<', 'file1' or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', 'file2' or die $!;

open my $out, '>', 'matches' or die $!;

while (my $line1 = <$fh1>) {

  seek $fh2, 0, 0;

  while (my $line2 = <$fh2>) {

    if ($line1 eq $line2) {
      print $out $line1;
      last;
    }
  }
}
```

---

**Edit**

Your comment has changed the problem. Both files have four-line records and you want to compare the second line in corresponding records across the two files.

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh1, '<', 'file1' or die $!;
open my $fh2, '<', 'file2' or die $!;

open my $match, '>', 'matches' or die $!;
open my $nomatch, '>', 'nomatch' or die $!;

while (1) {

  my (@data1, @data2);

  for (1 .. 4) {
    my $line;
    $line = <$fh1>;
    push @data1, $line if defined $line;
    $line = <$fh2>;
    push @data2, $line if defined $line;
  }

  last unless @data1 == 4 and @data2 == 4;

  if ($data1[1] eq $data2[1]) {
    print $match @data2;
  }
  else {
    print $nomatch @data2;
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry not any... I meant the following:

each record has 4 lines.. line 1 isthe header, line 2 is the sequence, line 3 is the spacer, line 4 is a string

Read record 1 from file 1 
extract line 2  
read record 1 from file 2
check if the sequence is a match 
if it is store it in a file 
else store it in no match file 
repeat ( meaning read record 2 from file 1...)

Answer (score 0):

A full example :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open F1, "<", "/path/1";
open F2, "<", "/path/2";

@a1 = <F1>;
@a2 = <F2>;

for (0..$#a1) {
    if ($a1[$_] eq $a2[$_]) {
        print "MATCH line [$_]\n";
    } else {
        print "DOESN'T MATCH line [$_]\n";
    }
}
```